# character to time with milliseconds and without date and tz

Tags: r, time

I have a character vector like below which hold time in the format HH:MM:SS.sss such that it can be used for time series analysis in a dataframe

```
x <- "05:17:55.703"
```

I wanted to convert it into timestamp with milliseconds without date and timezone - is this even possible ?

What have I tried ->

```
> as.POSIXct("05:17:55.703",format = "%H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2019-09-19 05:17:55 IST"
Issue is that, it doesn't show the milliseconds part and shows the date and timezone which I would like to avoid

> as.POSIXlt("05:17:55.703",format = "%H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2019-09-19 05:17:55 IST"
Issue is that, it doesn't show the milliseconds part and shows the date and timezone which I would like to avoid

> as.POSIXlt("05:17:55.703",format = "%H:%M:%S.%OS")
[1] "2019-09-19 05:17:55 IST"
Issue is that, it doesn't show the milliseconds part and shows the date and timezone which I would like to avoid

> strptime("05:17:55.703", "%H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2019-09-19 05:17:55 IST"
Issue is that, it doesn't show the milliseconds part and shows the date and timezone which I would like to avoid
```

Comment: Datetime objects must contain a date. However, I wonder why you care what is *shown*. The actual values should matter much more to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider to use `hms` from `lubridate` which will return a `"Period"` object

```
lubridate::hms(x)
#[1] "5H 17M 55.703S"
```

This shows millisecond part without date and timezone.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the hms package:

```r
hms::as_hms("05:17:55.703")
#> 05:17:55.703
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could use `as.POSIXct("05:17:55.703",format = "%H:%M:%OS")` and `options(digits.sec = 3)`. This should give  `"2022-03-28 05:17:55.703 CEST"`

```
as.POSIXct("05:17:55.703",format = "%H:%M:%OS")
options(digits.sec = 3)
#  "2022-03-28 05:17:55.703 CEST"
```